# Unable to open a MS Office word file from SharePoint Document library in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a link in my apx page which is hyper linked to a sharePoint document library ms word file, when I click the link MS word launches but unable to open the document, I receive the following error message, Using chrome solve the problem. problem with IE8.
Any idea?

```
Could not open 'http://myWeb:82/sites/A/B/myFile.docx
```

Comment: tried this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/162059?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Brijesh - your solution solved the issue.
Need to restart the computer after installing the fix